# Setting up TCP connections between S/C in Android/Java

Tags: android, tcp, multicast

I am designing a all-to-all Android program, including 5 nodes:

1. Each node acts as both server and client
2. Each node will connect to the other 4 nodes.
3. Each node will listen and accept the other 4 nodes' connections.

While I have the problem that, If the 5 nodes are launched in the order of:  1-2-3-4-5, Node1's tcp connection request will not be accepted by Node2, since Node2 is launched later than 1.

In order to solve this issue, i've tried using `isConnected()`, but it always returns `true` even when only Node1 is launched.

So my question is how to set up an all-to-all TCP connections among 3 Android nodes.

Attached is my code:

```
private class ClientTask extends Thread {
        Socket[] s1 = new Socket[5];

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int flag=1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if(flag==0) i--;
                try {
                    System.out.println("Begin making connections!");
                    //s1[i] = new Socket(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{10, 0, 2, 2}),REMOTE_PORT[i]);
                    s1[i] = new Socket();
                    s1[i].connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.0.2.2", REMOTE_PORT[i]),1000);
                    flag=1;
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    System.out.println("ClientTask UnknownHostException");
                    flag=0;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Error happens when set_redir.py is not run
                    System.out.println("ClientTask socket IOException");
                    flag=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the code for server:

```
public class ServerTask extends Thread {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Start listening!");
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10000);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error when creating serversocket!");
            }
            int flag=1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if(flag==0) i--;
                try {
                    // waiting for incoming socket
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    try{
                        out.writeBytes("You are connected to avd: " + (myPort-11108)/4);
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        System.out.println("Error here!");
                    }
                    flag=1;
                    // new thread for the full TCP connection
                    System.out.println("Receiving new TCP connection from " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                    tt[i] = new tcpThread(socket, i);
                    tt[i].start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: server socket");
                    flag=0;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("End listening...");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is 'S/C'? Short-circuit?

Comment: @EJP Server/Client...

Comment: Well why not say so? Everything isn't a TLA. Could have been anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing some research from Stackoverflow and google, I find the way to detect whether the server is online of offline. I'm writing the following notes in case someone else facing the same problem in the future :>

Instead of using `isConnected()`, which will always be `true` as long as the connection is indeed issued by the client, no matter the server is online or not, we can use `read()` or `readLine()`.

`read()` will return `-1` if the connection is not actually setup, due to the connection lost, server shutoff, etc.

`readLine()` will be clocking all the time, in the same situation as describe above.

So we can check whether the return value is `-1` or timeout the `readLine()` to check the status of TCP connections.

Comment: Errors everywhere here. If `read()` returns -1, `readLine()` will return `null` in the same situation, not block forever. `isConnected()` returns true forever after the socket has been either connected or accepted. It is an attribute of the socket, not of the connection. It isn't correct to state that `read()` will return -1 if the connection has been lost. The only way to detect that reliably is by sending. A read timeout can help, if you can distinguish between server inactivity and failure to respond.

Comment: @EJP Thx for your comments! I'm doing a project and facing quite a few TCP issues.  From the documentation of the return value of `read()`, `the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is reached.`. So why cant we say `read() will return -1 if the connection has been lost.`?

Comment: Because it might block forever. `read()` doesn't issue any network protocol, so it just waits for something to happen, and the only way something will happen on a dead connection is if you try to send to it.